# Optimize code for nested array values

Tags: c, arrays, caching, openmp, cpu

I'm looking for a best practice solution for optimize code which works with nested arrays. Value from one array use as index for second. I think current code is not cpu cache friendly code. Could I use openmp for optimize performance of this code ? If yes what is better use "for" or "sections" if PICK  not great 10?

```
#define bino4d(a,b,c,d) (base1[a]+base2[b]+base3[c]+base4[d])

static unsigned char _bits_[8] = { 0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x10, 0x08, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01 };
#define TSTBIT(ch,i) (ch[(i)>>3] & _bits_[(i) & 0x07])

lpmax = (PICK*(PICK - 1)*(PICK - 2)*(PICK - 3)) / 24;

    for (lp = 0; lp < lpmax; lp++)
    {

        j0 = I[LP4_0[lp]];
        j1 = I[LP4_1[lp]];
        j2 = I[LP4_2[lp]];
        j3 = I[LP4_3[lp]];
        ul = j0 + j1 + j2 + j3;

        //j0 = LP4_0[lp];
        //j1 = LP4_1[lp];
        //j2 = LP4_2[lp];
        //j3 = LP4_3[lp];
        //ul = bino4d(I[j0], I[j1], I[j2], I[j3]);
        if (TSTBIT(ToCover, ul)) s4++;
    }
```

Comment: what's the size of I and what's the range of LP4_*

Comment: LP4_* range is equal  210. For this code example PICK = 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using an extra array to store the partial results of `ul`, you might make the calculations more local and achieve better cache-friendliness or achieve parallelism. Assuming we have an array `UL[lpmax]=0`:

```
for (lp = 0; lp < lpmax; lp++)
    UL[lp] += I[LP4_0[lp]];

for (lp = 0; lp < lpmax; lp++)
    UL[lp] += I[LP4_1[lp]];

for (lp = 0; lp < lpmax; lp++)
    UL[lp] += I[LP4_2[lp]];

for (lp = 0; lp < lpmax; lp++)
    UL[lp] += I[LP4_3[lp]];

for (lp = 0; lp < lpmax; lp++)
    if (TSTBIT(ToCover, UL[lp])) s4++;
```

Comment: Interesting ideia. I'll check it.